# Restore BacPac database backup in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-backups, bacpac

I have database backup file with extension .bacpac so how can i restore it in sql server 2014 ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on the Databases folder in the Object Explorer tree.  Then click on "Import Data-tier application".  The wizard will guide you through the process.
- From the command line, run this command: `"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft sql server\120\dac\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /a:import /sf:"PATH_TO_YOUR_BACPAC_FILE" /tcs:"Data Source=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=NEW_DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=true"`

Aside: Note that the example connection string in the command line option above assumes you're using Windows Authentication instead of SQL Server authentication to access the server.